Vertices table generated by pgr_createTopology() doesn't have enough vertices
I get 7639 points using st_startpoint and st_endpoint, however the vertices table generated by pgr_createTopology only have 2393 points.

The red points are generated by pgr_createTopology, and the yellow points are generated by st_startpoint and st_endpoint

Furthermore I find some points from vertices table generated by pgr_createTopology are not startpoints or endpoints of the corresponding edges(the id column of the point corresponds to the source column of the line).
How can I make the vertices table generated by pgr_createTopology have as many points as those generated by st_startpoint and st_endpoint?

Looking at how evenly those are spread out, maybe you overshot the tolerance parameter and/or used the wrong unit (some CRS use degrees or miles instead of meters). Can you share some sample rows, table DDL and the queries you used to get these results, to make this reproducible?

Thank you so much, I use a smaller tolerance parameter and solve the problem.

As per the comment: this tends to happen when you set up the tolerance parameter too high, which is sometimes due to overlooking the CRS unit of measurement being a degree rather than a meter:

tolerance:
float8 Snapping tolerance of disconnected edges. (in projection unit)

Here's an example from somewhere in France: tolerance of 0.001 results in nodes ending up spaced out over 100m from each other (red dots) because the CRS used is degree-based 4326.
Dialing that down to 0.00001 solves the problem (green crosses).

It's worth pointing out you probably want to ST_Node() first, rather than just extract st_startpoint() and st_endpoint() of the raw road geometries you have. In both your example and mine you can see starts/ends will ignore some crossings, and noding adds in the missing points wherever two lines cross.
